# How can I center the hero text when resizing the browser down to iphone size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am struggling to come up with an ideal solution to handle a responsive hero text when the browser is rendered down to iphone size. Right now, unfortunately it looks like this:

[image]

This is the css I have regarding the hero section:

```
/* === HERO === */

#hero
{
    background: url("/wp-content/themes/threegreenbirds-daniel/images/grass-ground-new.jpg") 50% 0 repeat fixed;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 20%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

/* === MEDIA QUERIES === */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .logged-in .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 42px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .hero-text {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
      }
}
```

I tried this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {

  .hero-text {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
  }

  .hero-text:after {
    content: '';
    left: -9999px; 
    right: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

but it has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the additional conditions in your .hero-text class.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
.hero-text {
 left:0;
 right:0
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 }
```